# Can TinyMCE strip out the surrounding html - doctype, html and body tags?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to save a snippet of HTML formatted text that will be merged into a larger HTML doc (for HTML email). TinyMCE is saving my snippet with doctype, html and body elements. I only want what the user types in with HTML formatting.

Comment: To assist us further, are you able to share an example of your setup at https://fiddle.tiny.cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If TinyMCE is providing you an entire HTML document you likely have the `fullpage` plugin loaded:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/fullpage/

If you don't want a complete HTML document removing that plugin should cause TinyMCE to only return the HTML inside the `<body>` tag of the editor.